# Extjs function reference is false

Tags: extjs

I wanted to save a function reference to use it later like this

```
var fn = Ext.grid.column.Column.prototype.renderer;
```

and then

```
fn.apply(this, arguments);
```

but

```
Ext.grid.column.Column.prototype.renderer
```

is returning false.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `renderer` on the column prototype is `false`, which means there is no renderer, so no method is ever called.